# Comic Sans Missing from iOS Build

Tags: iphone

For some strange reason Comic Sans disappeared from my list of available fonts. The font does not show up on the simulator or on the device. OS X 10.6.7, 10.7, Xcode 4.01 or 4.2, iOS 4.3 or iOS 5.0. It will not show up.

It appears to be just my computer as any other device that I build with will not have that font show up either.

I am using:

```
 [UIFont fontWithName:@"ComicSansMS"]
```

I have also tried:

```
   [UIFont fontWithName:@"Comic Sans MS"]
```

nothing works. Comic Sans does appear on my computer though.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: It's Apple's way of improving your design.

Comment: Perhaps you have died and gone to a better place ;) (http://bancomicsans.com/). More seriously, that's odd.

Comment: LOL. You guys are so funny. I'm just a minion man, following orders :P

Comment: There should be a "comic sans" tag on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add it by yourself you add to you info.plist file a "Font provided by application" field that holds and array of values and then Item0 should equal a .ttf file that you import into you xcode project. So now you can use [UIFont fontWithName:@"NameOfFontThatWasAddedToYouPlist.ttf" size:@"20"];
And that will allow you have your app use any font:)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Thank you for contributing to this community.

Comment: The weird thing is that it worked before, so somehow my info.plist must have been modified.

Answer (score 12):

Apple's answer to Comic Sans is [Chalkboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalkboard_%28typeface%29).

This is how you use it in CSS:

```
font-family: "Comic Sans", "Comic Sans MS", "Chalkboard", "ChalkboardSE-Regular", sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe "Marker Felt" is available, and that's *almost* as bad.

(Family: Marker Felt Font: MarkerFelt-Thin)

Comment: this made me laugh.

Answer (score 2):

If yor are talking about iOS See [this](http://iosfonts.com/) list for available fonts.
If you want to add comic sans you have to add it by yourself.